# How can i get input from user of path from where i have to merge multiple excel file header and there file name into other excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, filenames

This is the code i have be working on but not sure how to merge them into one new excel file and get header and file name.

```
import os
import xlrd
 
Folder_path = input ("Enter the file path :")


def listDir(dir):
    fileNames = os.listdir(dir)
    
    loc = input ("Enter the path of file + filename :")

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

    # For row 0 and column 0 
    sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

    for i in range(sheet.ncols): 
        print(sheet.cell_value(0, i))
    
    for filename in fileNames:
        print(filename + sheet.cell_value(0, i))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    listDir(Folder_path)
```

from this code i can get the head value and file name but i want the put as show in the picture , where it should print in a new excel file the file name and output header of that particular file.

output should be as follow's
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bXoE.png

after i get file names i want to get header of each file and put in new excel file where it should show name file and there header .

Comment: first of all you may need to load the excel files and read them, I suggest openpyxl for that.

Comment: Thanks for that will look into it , but i have manage to pull up the file name and header name by using import xlrd but not sure how to assigned them by there file name.

Comment: good one, xlrd is good for excel too. You can associate file name and and header by a a dictionary for example.

Comment: but i have to only we path of file to get excel data files from there will Openpyxl work here , if it does pls give me a example , so that i can learn.

Comment: what do you mean by "..only we path of file.. " ?  | also in the title.. do you actually meant to write ".. file header and their file name.. " ?

Comment: Yes , i need to write the file name and header of each file in other file . like :- filename1 header of file1 , filename2 header of file2.

Comment: @promodkumar please post the code you have now with xlrd and we'll take it from there to produce the output you need

Comment: @jayvee I have updated the code , but i need output filename aline with header of that file and thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of doing it:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

def listDir(inputdir):
    allheaders=[]
    fileNames = os.listdir(inputdir)
    
    for filename in fileNames:
        headers=[filename]
        loc = os.path.join(Folder_path, filename)

        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

        for i in range(sheet.ncols):
            headers.append(sheet.cell_value(0, i))
           
        allheaders.append(headers)
    return allheaders

Enter_path =input("Enter the file path :")
Folder_path = Path(Enter_path)  

allheaders=listDir(Folder_path)
    
df=pd.DataFrame(allheaders)
df.to_excel("ListOfHeaders.xlsx",header=False, index=False)
```